# SQL IF statement is being ignored

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement

I have a long script and I like to be able to just run the whole file when I need to and not worry about if parts of it have already ran. But the script below is giving me problems. For some reason it is getting past the IF statement even when the columns 'EntityID' and 'EntityType' do not exist, in which case it should not get through the IF statement. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Notes' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('EntityId', 'EntityType'))
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        --Delete notes where EntityType and EntityID are both NULL
        DELETE FROM [dbo].[Notes]
        WHERE [EntityId] = NULL 
        AND [EntityType] = NULL
        --Delete notes where the corresponding contact or account has been deleted.
        OR [ID] IN (9788, 10684, 10393, 10718, 10719)

        --Populate new columns with all existing data
        UPDATE [dbo].[Notes]
        SET [AccountId] = [EntityId]
        WHERE [EntityType] = 1

        UPDATE [dbo].[Notes]
        SET [ContactId] = [EntityId]
        WHERE [EntityType] = 2

        --Delete EntityId and EntityType columns from the Notes table
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Notes]
        DROP COLUMN [EntityId], [EntityType]
    COMMIT
END
GO
```

The script for the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Notes](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AnnotationID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [NoteText] [ntext] NULL,
    [OriginalAnnotationID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
    [ContactId] [int] NULL,
    [AccountId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Notes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Notes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Account_ID] FOREIGN KEY([AccountId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Account] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Notes] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Account_ID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Notes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ContactId_ID] FOREIGN KEY([ContactId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Contact] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Notes] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ContactId_ID]
GO
```

The errors:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'EntityId'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'EntityType'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'EntityType'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'EntityType'.
```

Comment: Are you sure the columns don't exist? - try sticking the `select `statement in above the `IF` and see what (if anything) it returns

Comment: returns false only if none of the columns exist. So if one or the other does...

Comment: Is it possible there is a table named `Notes` that is in a different schema? You should specify `TABLE_SCHEMA` as well. Or better yet, use `sys.columns` (read this: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information-schema-views.aspx)

Comment: @JonEgerton I had not thought of that, but it returned nothing. So the problem still exists.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thats an interesting article. Thanks for that. I need to specify both `Table` and `Columns` though because I have hundreds of tables with similar columns on them(FK and PK). so unless I misunderstand how to use `sys.columns` then I don't think I can use that here.

Comment: You can just say `WHERE name IN ('EntityId', 'EntityType') AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Notes')` - however you are constantly dropping columns on hundreds of tables? Something smells kind of wrong here.

Comment: Also you can't say `WHERE something = NULL` you need to say `WHERE something IS NULL`...

Comment: @AaronBertrand You misunderstood, I RARELY drop columns. I just have lots of Table with the same column names(I don't like it but its how the guys that initialized the system here built it). But I tried `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.COLUMNS WHERE name IN ('EntityId', 'EntityType') AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Notes'))` and I get the same result..

Comment: Well that returns true if one columns exists *or* if both columns exist. So if you try to drop two columns and only one of them exists... if the IF block is entering and neither column exists, there's something else you're not telling us. Can you show us a whole repro (e.g. create a table where those columns exist but the IF block still gets entered)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm telling you everything I know. Both columns existed and I replaced them with AccountId and ContactId. The first time I ran this script it ran flawlessly and did exactly what I wanted. But now that that columns do not exist it errors out when it shouldn't. I did not change anything in the whole script file either.

Comment: So script that table (right-click, script table as), confirm that your script still errors out on it, and show us both. You're telling us the sky is green but we have no way to confirm or deny because we can't see your sky.

Comment: Yep I get the same thing if I try `CREATE TABLE Notes([ID]  int)` then try your script (cut down to just the `DELETE` statement). IIRC SQL Server will ignore the `IF` statements when it compiles the script and will compile every statement except if it references a non existent object in which case it will be subject to a deferred compile.

Comment: @AaronBetrand I editd my post to include the scripted table and the error I'm getting.

Comment: @MartinSmith +1 good catch on the parsing rules

Comment: @MartinSmith So are you saying I should check if the new columns exist or not instead of the old columns? So I should say `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Notes' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('AccountId', 'ContactId'))` ??

Comment: @Fourthmeal70 no, he's saying you could put `IF (1 = 0)` there and the parser is still going to trip you up and return errors if the code inside the conditional references columns that don't exist (deferred name resolution works for *object* that don't exist, but not for *columns*). How is it that you're running all these scripts but you don't know whether these columns exist yet or not? Anyway a workaround, as I posted in my answer, is to use dynamic SQL inside the conditional.

Comment: @Fourthmeal70 - The only way of avoiding it is to run the statement in a child scope with `EXEC` AFAIK (well there is another way in theory in that every statement could reference a meaningless temporary table that isn't created until inside the `IF` but that seems quite horrible)

Comment: Also seems that the reference to the non existent table has to occur before the reference to the missing column for that to work.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ahh ok, the reason I don't know if columns exist or not is because these scripts get run on three different databases(Dev, Staging, Production) and refreshes get done on occassion that may affect one or more of the databases so instead of investigating I just re-run the scripts on all databeses.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ok Thanks! That seems to do the job although, I'm not a fan of it. I will definitely keep these parsing rules in mind in the future!

Comment: You should be building a proper deployment script for each environment, IMHO. Having a big script and just letting parts of it fail seems very haphazard and error-prone to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Martin was definitely onto something. The stuff inside the `IF` is being treated by the parser at parse time and ignoring whether your `IF` will pan out. This is the same reason you can't do:

```
IF 1 = 1
  CREATE TABLE #x(a INT);
ELSE
  CREATE TABLE #x(b INT);
```

One workaround would be to use dynamic SQL:

```
IF EXISTS ...
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @sql = N'
        DELETE FROM [dbo].[Notes]
        WHERE [EntityId] IS NULL 
        AND [EntityType] IS NULL
        --Delete notes where the corresponding contact or account has been deleted.
        OR [ID] IN (9788, 10684, 10393, 10718, 10719)

        --Populate new columns with all existing data
        UPDATE [dbo].[Notes]
        SET [AccountId] = [EntityId]
        WHERE [EntityType] = 1

        UPDATE [dbo].[Notes]
        SET [ContactId] = [EntityId]
        WHERE [EntityType] = 2

        --Delete EntityId and EntityType columns from the Notes table
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Notes]
        DROP COLUMN [EntityId], [EntityType]';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

But you still should be sure that *both* columns are there.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that one of the columns exist but not both.  Try the following:

```
IF 2 = (SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Notes' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('EntityId', 'EntityType'))
```

Comment: Neither of the two columns exist right now. I tried your suggestion and I get the same exact error: `invalid column name 'EntityId'`

Comment: Is it possible that you have a view in another schema with the same name (Notes)?