# Inserting into one Temp table with If condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL IF statement is being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161065/sql-if-statement-is-being-ignored)
>   [Odd error using IF/ELSE IF statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254462/odd-error-using-if-else-if-statements)

I'm trying to do inserting into one temptable. But it is throwing an error. Please help

```
Declare @Live BIT = 'True'

Step 1:-  
If @Live = 'True'
    BEGIN 
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL  
        DROP TABLE #tempTable
        SELECT TOP 1 INTO #tempTable FROM Table1

    END
    ELSE

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL  
        DROP TABLE #tempTable
        SELECT TOP 5 INTO #tempTable FROM Table1

Step 2:-
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL  
DROP TABLE #tempTable
If @Live = 'True'
    BEGIN         
        SELECT TOP 1 INTO #tempTable FROM Table1            
    END
    ELSE
        SELECT TOP 5 INTO #tempTable FROM Table1
```

In Step1 & Step2, error showing as

> "There is already an object named '#tempTable' in the database."

**Condition:** I have to insert the records into one #tempTable

Is there any other alternate to achieve this requirement?

Comment: What is `TOP` without `ORDER BY` supposed to do? You can parameterise `TOP (@N)` conditionally then just have one `SELECT TOP (@N) INTO ...` But I'm not sure of your logic. What is the point of step 1 if you instantly drop the table in step 2 anyway.

Comment: @Aaron, sorry, Just tried, thats not working. Thank You

Comment: @AaronBertrand - When a question gets closed as a duplicate any comments that contain a link to one of the proposed dupes automatically get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend delcaring the temp table before hand then using an `INSERT INTO` instead of a `SELECT INTO`

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL  
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #tempTable
END

CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(
   --columns go here
)

If @Live = 'True'
BEGIN         
    INSERT INTO #tempTable
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table1            
END
ELSE
    INSERT INTO #tempTable
    SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Table1
```

Comment: Superu. working now. Am able to insert the mutliple records. Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 0):

run this command before running query cause there is already a #tempTable

DROP TABLE #tempTable

and try this code

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') is not null
drop table #tempTable

create table #tempTable (a int)
insert into #tempTable (a) select 1

select * from #tempTable